# Windows 8 keeps crashing with different message every time

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

my windows 8.1 keeps crashing with different causes in the blue screen: tcpip.sys, ntfs .. (sorry didn't remember them all)

here is the link for all the minidumps I found in the system: hxxps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6YlXYX1hRlDRkhUMW9uMDBqMDQ/edit?usp=sharing

I would be very thankful for any kind of help.

thanks in advance

EDIT: chkdsk /r report

```
Checking file system on C:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Windows.

A disk check has been scheduled.
Windows will now check the disk.                         

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  441600 file records processed.                                                         File verification completed.
  4422 large file records processed.                                      0 bad file records processed.                                      
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  571332 index entries processed.                                                        Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.                                           0 unindexed files recovered.                                       
Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Cleaning up 899 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 899 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 899 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  64867 data files processed.                                            CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  37496656 USN bytes processed.                                                            Usn Journal verification completed.

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
  441584 files processed.                                                                File data verification completed.

Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
  202584007 free clusters processed.                                                        Free space verification is complete.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the
master file table (MFT) bitmap.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the volume bitmap.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.

 957168639 KB total disk space.
 146076228 KB in 372685 files.
    180040 KB in 64868 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    576339 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 810336032 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 239292159 total allocation units on disk.
 202584008 allocation units available on disk.

Internal Info:
00 bd 06 00 1b ab 06 00 be ee 0a 00 00 00 00 00  ................
da 01 00 00 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....!...........

Windows has finished checking your disk.
Please wait while your computer restarts.
```

Comment: The latest crash has a bug check code `0x24`, which translates to `NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM`: "This indicates a problem occurred in `ntfs.sys`, the driver file that allows the system to read and write to NTFS drives." Start by opening a command prompt as administrator and run this command: `chkdsk %systemdrive% /r` Give the required confirmation and restart Windows to check the file system. If you're still getting the same issues, check the disk health status using the diagnostic tool provided by the manufacturer. In case the disk is fine, try [performing a clean boot](http://bit.ly/1imEv6a).

Comment: I run the chkdsk tool, I've edited the question with the output since it's too long. what about the times it was complaining about tcpip.sys or other things ? is it related to ntfs also ?

Comment: The `chkdsk` utility fixed all problems encountered, nothing particularly bad anyway. What's the exact disk model? Run this command as administrator to check whether the system files are okay: `sfc /scannow` The operating system should be Windows 8.1 Update 64-bit. The computer is a laptop, and the series is **HP ENVY 17 Leap Motion SE NB PC**. There are few different models, though. What's yours? Was Windows 8.1 already installed when you bought it? As for the crashes, there's only one targeting `tcip.sys`, but it's probably unrelated. As hinted by Jamie, stop overclocking if you are.

Comment: it gives: Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
the system disk is a one partition 1TB disk, 16GB of ram, it came installed with 8.0 and I upgraded to 8.1.
I'm not overclocking

Comment: What's the exact laptop/disk model? If you need to test the RAM, you can use [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) (make sure to run it for at least 8-10 hours, though). As for the latest crash, it seems `VBoxNetFlt.sys` (VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver) is somewhat related. Consider updating VirtualBox to latest version.

Comment: when pressing fn+esc I get only "HP ENVY 17 Leap Motion SE NB PC", how can I get the model ? I uninstalled VirtualBox, I'm waiting for the next crash to happen (hope it doesn't)

Comment: This article should get started: [HP Notebook PCs - How Do I Find My Model Number or Product Number?](http://bit.ly/1pDUL5C) Regarding the hard disk model, you should be able to retrieve it from the Device Manager. You said you uninstalled some unused tools. For reference, could you specify what did you remove/change, exactly? Also, in case you haven't already, make sure to [disable the automatic restart after crashes](http://bit.ly/1mp2UqL). This way you can view the tech details even when the system is unable to save a `.dmp` file. BTW, how old is the system? Did you check the temps yet?

Comment: Model: Product number: F6R70EA#A2N.
Disk: HGST HTS541010A9E680.

I've uninstalled all cyberlink apps that came installed, and a few disk recovery software I had installed in the past (easyrecovery, gary undelete ...), VirtualBox ... (that's what I remember).
the system is less than a year old.
you mean %TEMP% ? if yes there is like 7GB of data there, can this cause troubles ?

Comment: Get [Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=612&sid=3), run both the quick and the extended tests, and then post here the results. As for "temps", I actually meant *temperatures* (I was running out of available characters, sorry). You might use [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) or a similar tool. If you want you can run also run the built-in disk cleanup tool (`cleanmgr.exe`), although it's not strictly necessary. Monitor the situation for a few days, and if the system doesn't crash, consider reinstalling VirtualBox.

Comment: thanks, I'll follow your suggestions and monitor for a few days and post the results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the last 8 of your minidumps. They are a lot less varied than I'd thought from your OP.

All either reference network (NDIS) or NTFS. In all NDIS cases, a filter driver from VirtualBox is on the stack. In all NTFS cases, there is no direct evidence of Vbox but the file system filter manager is active.

No other visible components are what I'd call likely suspects.

I've had BSODs with Virtual Box before. I would disable VBox, if only to see if that helps. If it helps, be sure your copy of Vbox is up to date, or switch to some other VM host like the free version of VMware.

Answer (score 0):

The chkdsk output isn't likely to be helpful.

tcpip.sys is part of the networking stack. A failure in tcpip.sys is unlikely to be related to problems in ntfs.

BSODs that identify a variety of different components are usually due to hardware issues, such as memory errors, overclocked or undervoted or overheating CPUs, weak power supplies... that sort of thing. Your next step should be to run memtest with many passes.

Comment: since my last post I had a bsod about bad_pool_caller, here is the mini dump generated hxxps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6YlXYX1hRlDUnI4NUg5czY5RE0/edit?usp=sharing
any good memory test tool (free) ?

Comment: memtest86 is fee. Also, Windows since Windows Vista has come with standalone memory tester. It's available from the F8 / ctrl-F8 menu.

Comment: er, that's supposed to be "memtest85 is free" above :)

Comment: I looked at the last 8 of your minidumps. They are a lot less varied than I'd thought from your OP. All either reference network (NDIS) or NTFS. In all NDIS cases, a filter driver from VirtualBox is on the stack. In all NTFS cases, there is no direct evidence of Vbox but the file system filter manager is active. No other visible components are what I'd call likely suspects. 

I've had BSODs with Virtual Box before. I would disable VBox, if only to see if that helps. If it helps, be sure your copy of Vbox is up to date, or switch to some other VM host like the free version of VMware.

Comment: It is often not possible to give a definitive answer to "why is my system crashing?" - even if you have full memory dumps. In this case we have only minidumps. However my comment just above yours gives a definite suggestion for a next step.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, my laptop was diagnosing memory for the last 36 hours and found no problems; I've uninstalled VirtualBox along with some unused tools, let's see if the crashes stop now

Comment: thanks @JamieHanrahan virtualbox seems to be the problem, please add an answer and I'll accept it